# What is the most efficient way to replace a 14" rough-in toilet with a 12" rough-in toilet?

Tags: toilet

I want to replace my failing 14" rough-in toilet. It seems the world has moved on to 12" rough-in as a standard. Would it be crazy to put a 1" thick board on the wall to provide some stability to the tank and install a 12" rough-in toilet?

Also, the toilet appears to be 50 years old but, being ceramic, the tank is still viable. Would a 50 year old tank from a 14" rough-in work with a modern 12" rough-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toilets do not require any stability from a wall or any other surface other than a flat floor to set on. Even if the floor is not, shims can be used to correct that.

The 14" rough in, with a 12" toilet will leave a 2 1/2" to 3" gap at the wall, nothing else

You still can order toilets with a 14" rough in, try a plumbing supply, not the big box stores.

The tank from the 14" toilet may work on a 12" bowl, but toilets are sold with tanks typically together, not separate from their tanks.

Comment: ^^this, and just to echo... you don't want to try and bodge an old tank with a new bowl. Plumbing is hard enough without playing Don Quixote.

Comment: I have done what the OP suggests about the tank, and that is correct, it is not worth it...

Comment: Thanks. So a 12" in a 14" situation will appear oddly distanced from the wall but all else will be hunky-dory?

Comment: Yes, that will be the only issue, the bigger than usual space. But I am a little anal, and I would do what I could to locate a 14" toilet

Comment: Most big box stores carry a  2" offset closet flange adapter.like Oatey  436064. I can't say if they make clogs more frequent or not. In my bath I installed a 12" bowl then cut a block of wood to fill the space between the wall and the tank and covered it with tile that matched the wall. That way if someone leaned back they won't crack the tank.

Comment: @mikes, I do not know if it still holds true, but offset were not allowable by code at one time. You could still purchase them, but were not legal to use.